# Kendo ui Multi Select Remove Selected element using value

Tags: kendo-ui, multi-select

I am using kendo ui multiple select

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/multiselect/events.html

i have this code

```
var data =
        [
            { text: "Africa", value: "1" },
            { text: "Europe", value: "2" },
            { text: "Asia", value: "3" },
            { text: "North America", value: "4" },
            { text: "South America", value: "5" },
            { text: "Antarctica", value: "6" },
            { text: "Australia", value: "7" }
        ];

var multi = $("#select").kendoMultiSelect({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: data
}).data("kendoMultiSelect");
```

now i can add the values using this

```
multi.value(["5", "3"]);
```

now i want to remove from the selected values

is there any way to remove the values using `value` or `text`

for example if i want to remove `5` then is there any method like `multi.remove(["5"]);`

or any other way to remove it???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For removing element from a MultiSelect programmatically, you can use:

```
// Elements to be removed
var subtract = ["1", "5"];
// Get copy of current selected elements
var values = multi.value().slice();
// Remove elements from subtract
values = $.grep(values, function(a) {
    return $.inArray(a, subtract) == -1;
});
// Clean filtering
multi.dataSource.filter({});
// Set new values
multi.value(values);
```

Where `subtract` are the elements to be removed (in this example "1" and "5").

**TIP:** For adding, you can use:

```
// Elements to add
var add = ["4", "5"];
// Get copy of current selected elements
var values = multi.value().slice();
// Merge withe elements to add
var merge = $.merge(values, add);
// Clean filtering
multi.dataSource.filter({});
// Remove duplicates and set them back
multi.value($.unique(merge));
```

Running example in here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/9WfGA/

Comment: thanx for replay but it works `prefect` only when i use `value:["1", "2", "3"] `. if you don't use values then select manually `asia`, `Europe` (select using type and enter) after that click to set values it will not work

Comment: here is the running example [http://jsfiddle.net/mitesh_inf/9WfGA/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/mitesh_inf/9WfGA/3/)

Comment: Actually the problem is with typing. It has nothing to do with numbers nor with initial values. As far as you select values with the mouse it works fine. Even if you display the values that I'm setting you will see that they are correct so not sure if it is a bug on MultiSelect (they already fixed one in release 710 but this does not seem to be fixed). Anyway I will take another look into it.

Comment: Check your fiddle working here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/9WfGA/4/ I also update my answer to reflect the change. I need to do a `dataSource.filter({})` before setting new values.

Comment: thanx it solve this issue. in my case i have more than `40000` options so when i use `dataSource.filter({})` system becomes `Super Slow` is there any other way..???

Comment: Are you applying some filtering to avoid reading the 40000? Basically there is a problem(?) with MultiSelect that when you type it uses filtering for finding the option **but** when you choose an option they should remove the filtering but they don't do it, so we have to do it by ourselves. One question, do you always use keyboard? I guess so if you have so many options. Does not work for you autocomplete?

Comment: i am using button to set some values based on region at that time this became slow. it works fine if i use only 15-20 nodes. i am not using keyboard all the time.

Comment: If you remove the `filtering` and you don't use they keyboard, functionally it should work but is it still slow? (I know that in the final scenario you want keyboard but I'm trying to isolate where is the problem and see if I can find a workaround).

Comment: Any suggestion how to add items to multi select when it's bound to remote data source?

Comment: @MiNT, do you mean that you want to use the multi select for adding items to a DataSource that happens to be remote? Do you have any open question in SO for this?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm creating a new option/item in a modal window and i want to add the new option in the selected values. I haven't created a SO question yet. I'll create it tomorrow and post the link here :)

Comment: @OnaBai see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132182/how-to-set-initial-values-to-kendo-ui-multiselect-with-remote-data-source

Answer (score -2):

This is already answered but this mught help someone. I had the same issue, wanted to remove values but didn't had the values to remove. [This](https://www.telerik.com/forums/multiselect---removing-selected-data-items-from-dropdown-list) helped me out. It will remove all the selected values from dropdown

Add a css class to page

```
.hide-selected > li.k-state-selected {
    display: none;
}
```

and add this code to `pageload`

```
var multiselect= $("#select").data("kendoMultiSelect");
multiselect.ul.addClass('hide-selected');
```

Comment: This is just css, it doesn't "remove" anything except the css class.